# SSRS Reports, Group filtering

Tags: sql, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I have groups with specific filters. Within these groups I have few "Count" expression with conditions. All works great. But when group doesn't have any elements then it disappears. But I need to show in "Count" cells "0" for this group. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add the SQL query you are using to the question, and indicate which fields you are grouping on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two suggestions.

In your query use an ISNULL function.

```
 Select
 ISNULL(YourExpression, 0)
 From Table
```

In SSRS Use an expression for the fields you want to eliminate nulls.

```
 iif(fields!Field.Value is nothing , 0 , Fields!Field.Value)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

use the below expression:

```
=iif(isnothing(Field!Name.value),0,count(Field!Name.value))
```